# Set tag abbreviations for custom views on XML

Tags: java, android, xml

In my app **I extend** `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, so every time I need to declare a layout in XML (which you may know it's quite often) I need to **write a long tag**, in order to point to the view's package.

So the XML files look like this:

```
<com.company.material.widget.LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.company.material.widget.RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_height"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Text.Field.Small"
            android:id="@+id/form_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/Button.Main"
            android:id="@+id/form_submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </com.company.material.widget.RelativeLayout>

    <com.company.essentials.view.FormView
        android:id="@+id/formview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
```

This is chaotic!

Is there any way to abbreviate this? Like `AppLinearLayout` instead of `com.company.material.widget.LinearLayout`?

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your View class to the `android.view` package. This would allow you to just write `<AppRelativeLayout />` instead of `<com.company.material.widget.AppRelativeLayout />`, since View tag names without package prefixes are 'auto-completed' to the `android.view` package.

If you don't want to move your whole class to this package, you may just create a dummy sub-class à la:

```
package android.view;

public class AppRelativeLayout extends com.company.material.widget.RelativeLayout {
    // same constructors as super class
    public AppRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

You just have to make sure you don't use the same class names as the Android framework already does, such as `RelativeLayout`, since that would clash with the existing views and layout names. That's why I named the example above `AppRelativeLayout`.

Comment: **That does work** and keeps the code clean as I wanted. Smart idea. Thank you!

Comment: This is a terrible idea. If Android ever adds a class with the same name, you'll get that class instead of yours; the framework takes precedence over your APK.

Comment: @j__m theoretically true, but if you set some prefix to your class names, it's very unlikely to happen that Android will ever add a class with the very same name.

Answer (score 1):

If it's worth it to you, you can customize your activity's layout inflater.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LayoutInflater.Factory {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle _icicle) {
        super.onCreate(_icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    }

    @Override public Object getSystemService(String _name) {
        Object service = super.getSystemService(_name);
        if(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(_name)) {
            LayoutInflater myInflater = ((LayoutInflater)service).cloneInContext(this);
            myInflater.setFactory(this);
            return myInflater;
        }
        return service;
    }

    @Override public View onCreateView (String _tag, Context _ctx, AttributeSet _as) {
        if("mytag".equals(_tag))
            return new MyLinearLayout(_ctx, _as);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

`setContentView` will call `getSystemService` to obtain a layout inflater, and for each tag that layout inflater will query each of its factories (including our custom one) to see if the factory knows how to create the object that corresponds to that tag.

Comment: It's seems a good idea. But that way I need to manually instantiate every type of view, not only the custom ones, right? If so, I understand what you are saying with _"if it's worth it"_...

Comment: No, I thought I was clear -- you only need to instantiate your custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative option as well if you like you can do it like this

```
<view
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.company.material.widget.LinearLayout" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Yeah, it's possible this way, but calling View to everything won't improve organization and won't clean up code. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: To do it this way you must use a lowercase v (`<view>` not `<View>`).